# How to describe your experience in your CV/Resume without breaking copyright / GDPR rules?

Tags: copyright, software, gdpr

Are there rules (EU & US) defining how far one can go in decribing his professional experience as a software developer, and telling about the projects he worked on?

For example, if I do not include any line of source code, I rename the real project names with fake ones (Ex: Project Atalantis, Backoffice Gamma, etc.) and I avoid diving into deep details. Though, still tell the technical stack (Ex: Java8, AWS, CURL, etc).

A description that might look like this, would it be legal ?
*I provided content managers with fine control over the end-user’s web portal. Solutions overcame the challenge of balancing between SPA, intuitive frontend and fast backend that wires up new Symfony4 applications with a legacy monolith.
TechStack: #Doctrine #Symfony4 #jQuery #CSS #SPA #Bootstrap #DTO #SOA #Elasticsearch
It would be fine for me even if you provide me with links or hint to check :)*

Comment: I struggle to see how anything one might want to put on a CV comes anywhere near GDPR or copyright issues.

Comment: ok, something more like NDA? won't you be in trouble if you very deeply describe how you implement something in a detailed technical terms?

Comment: That would depend on the specific terms of the NDA.

Comment: The most common form of it that would be included in most of software development contracts, nothing Classified I'd say like GOV or so

Comment: If your question is actually about an NDA, you'll probably want to post a new question addressing that. Besure to identify what jurisdiction's laws would be controlling.